# Show x, y and curve names when cursor on the graph data in ZedGraph in C#

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I try to show X,Y and the name of the curve which was drawn on the graph when cursor comes on it. I used

```
 zedGraphControl1.IsShowPointValues = true;
```

but it isn't enough. I need also curve name. When the cursor is on the curve in the graph information should be shown like that:

```
12/27/2010 12:09 AM, 49.94, ACTIVE_MW
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Dont anyone know the answer of this question? :(

Answer (score 9):

It is possible.  You can add an event handler to the PointValueEvent event that gets fired when you mouse-over a point.

Something like:

```
this.zedGraphControl1.PointValueEvent += new ZedGraph.ZedGraphControl.PointValueHandler(this.zedGraphControl1_PointValueEvent);

private string zedGraphControl1_PointValueEvent(ZedGraph.ZedGraphControl sender, ZedGraph.GraphPane pane, ZedGraph.CurveItem curve, int iPt)
{
   return curve.Label.Text + " - " + curve.Points[iPt].ToString();
}
```